# OptmisticLockingException on inside field

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have this Person class that is part of various other transactions like a Sale or a payment for example. I have this Person class linked to the payment and Sale as well with no cascading. So when I want to persist a Sale that also has payments. I do this.

OBS: I have the SalesBean, PaymentBean, PersonBean

1 - The Sales Bean tries to persist the payment first.
2 - The SalesBean calls the PaymentBean.persistPayment() to persist the payment.
Inside the PaymentBean.persistPayment(), the PersonBean is called to persist the Person that is assigned back to the payment when the persistPerson() returns. and the payment is persisted and returned to the SalesBean.
3 - In the SalesBean, it gets the returned payment, gets the now existing customer, assigns back to the Sale entity and tries to persist it.

At this time, I get OptmisticLockingException complaining that the Telephone inside the customer has been changed, deleted etc since it was last read. I don't think this is true because I'm in the early stages of development and I'm calling this method from a Unit test case.

OBS:
1 - All entities inherit the version field from one AbstractEntity

P.S: I, later, tried to do a refresh() using the SalesBean's entity manager but I get an EntityNotFoundException, even checking first with EntityManager.contains().

```
public class Person extends AbstractCRMEntity {

    static private final long serialVersionUID = 201111151919L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    ...

    @JoinTable(name="PERSON_TELEPHONES")
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Telephone> telephones;
```

---

```
public class Telephone extends AbstractCRMEntity {

    static private final long serialVersionUID = 201111151918L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TelephoneID phone;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="telephones", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Person> owners;
```

---

```
if (saleEntity.getOwner() != null && saleEntity.getOwner().getId() <= 0) {
    OpResult clientResult = personManager.persistPerson(saleEntity.getOwner());
    if (clientResult.getOutcome().equals(OpResult.FAILURE)) {
        retorno.append(clientResult);
    } else {
            Person client = (Person) clientResult.getResult();
//                if (em.contains(client)) {
//                  logger.log(Level.INFO, "SalesManagerBean refresh client {0}", client.getName());
//                  em.refresh(client);
//                } else {
//                  logger.log(Level.INFO, "SalesManagerBean find client {0}", client.getName());
//                        client = em.find(Person.class, client.getId());
//                }
                saleEntity.setOwner((Person) clientResult.getResult());
        }
}


********************************

if (availableCreditToPay.compareTo(saleEntity.getBalance().getAmount()) > 0) {
    em.merge(saleEntity);
        // APLLY THE PAYMENTS TO THE SALE UNTIL PAID ...
} else { // not enough unapplied payments to pay
    BigDecimal unpaidDifference = saleEntity.getBalance().getAmount().subtract(availableCreditToPay);
        if (saleEntity.getOwner().getCreditLimit() != null && saleEntity.getOwner().getCreditLimit().getAmount() != null  && saleEntity.getOwner().getCreditLimit().getAmount().floatValue() >= unpaidDifference.floatValue()) { // customer has credit limit
            em.merge(saleEntity);
        } else { // customer does not have credit limit
            if (saleEntity.getCoSigner() == null ? false : (saleEntity.getCoSigner().getCreditLimit().getAmount().floatValue() >= unpaidDifference.floatValue())) {
                    em.merge(saleEntity);
                }
        }
}

**********************************
```

The first block of code is executed before the merges. I try to check if the customer has been persisted already. If not, I try to persist it. Sometimes the customer is persisted here, but most of the time is persisted before with a similar call like "                paymentManager.persistCreditTransaction(currentPmt);" that persists any payment, if any, from this customer that consequently persists the Person and assigns it back to the saleEntity

Comment: Show us the code which causes the exception, and the stack trace of the exception. Side note: You don't want cascade=ALL on a ManyToMany: it will try to delete all the telephones of a person when deleting a person, although these telephones are used by other persons.

Comment: Hi, I added the code you requested. Thanks for the tip about the cascade=ALL. I had it without the cascade=REMOVE, but I had changed to ALL to try to resolve this issue, but would eventually forget or not change it back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are merging the same object multiple times from the same original.

i.e.

- you get an object with version 1
- you merge it (committed version is now 2, but your local copy's version is still 1)
- you call merge again, and get a lock error, because you are trying to commit old data

You need to update you local copy after each merge, by returning the committed object after each commit, or the start of each transaction.

Comment: Thanks James, that was exactly what happened, but after many hours looking for the problem, you go blind. Reading your suggestion, I first thought it couldn't be because I was assigning the responses back and I was just getting the erros only on the Telephones relationship inside Person. So, I decided to take a look again at my code that persist the Person. Before merging the Person, I was looping through the relationship and checking each Telephone and substituting with an existing one from the DB. The error was in this loop.